# No Apps - Using 2 of 3 gears

Tags: openshift, openshift-gears

I deleted an app from the web console but there was an error. After that, the system shows no apps but says that I am using 2 of 3 gears. Anyone knows how to solve this issue?

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps not the most direct answer, but one avenue to try would be the command line interface rhc. If you install that, and try using it, you may have more success in figuring it out. I believe rhc is supposed to me more full featured than the web interface.

for steps on how to get started with rhc, look here https://www.openshift.com/get-started and click on the Command Line heading.

Comment: Thanks Giggity Gee. I tried to look any options from rhc command but still no clue yet.